# How to Parse API All Format MRZ Passport, ID C# WinForm Application

Tags: c#, documents, readable

String for example:

1)

```
IDD<-LG11T92P12<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
4221082<1004080D<<<<<<<<<<<<<0
TAVAEV<-OLBA<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

2)

```
P<-TURCEMİL<-HABER<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
U113789201TUR9151151M201124257094239218<<<26
```

3)

```
I<-TURA19C211797<17886454814<<<
8904241M2802068TUR<<<<<<<<<<<<
6TASCELIK<-HABER<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

etc.

ID card, passport, visas, etc. How to parse? 
Name, surname, document number, etc.
I need an API or SDK.

Example picture:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Wi7nHCvFk182SVV3u9Zg9zH2pPWc52f3

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to recognize text in an image?

Comment: No,
Like this. like the link .
1-)  https://github.com/newtondev/mrz-parser
2-)  https://github.com/ZsBT/mrz-java

Passport,ID,VİSA etc. so do ALL MRZ